# "Break into" vs "break up into" vs "break down into"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

I was writing the following sentence:

"you should break this long paragraph into smaller ones."

For a moment, I wondered whether I should add something between *paragraph* and *into*.

I searched on Google and I found three variations:

[break this long paragraph up into](https://medium.com/@cbblackmon/i-think-you-should-break-this-long-paragraph-up-into-several-smaller-ones-because-that-will-make-it-613a26f96913)

[break that long paragraph down into](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=IwAYDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT62&lpg=PT62&dq=%22should%20break%20that%20long%20paragraph%22&source=bl&ots=qtTw8ABGgX&sig=ACfU3U2vsfXnBUahn4KgbaJNQrMtEg5ybw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8h4jek5jgAhVEO7wKHZJzCekQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22should%20break%20that%20long%20paragraph%22&f=false)

And my original version.

Maybe all of them are the correct answer? But when, how do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All alternatives are perfectly natural, and it would be overscrupulous to suppose any difference in meaning (or even *fine nuance* of meaning) attaches to the choice. But the general principle is always *simpler is better / less is more*, so I suggest you [stick with the majority of native speakers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=break%20the%20problem%20into%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20up%20into%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20down%20into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20up%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20down%20into%3B%2Cc0)...

[image]

---

It might just be worth pointing out that you can *break [some complex entity] **up*** (or ***...down***) without actually specifying the "lower level parts" that would thereby result. As the results from [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=break%20the%20problem%20and%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20up%20and%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20down%20and&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbreak%20the%20problem%20down%20and%3B%2Cc0) for *break the problem [nothing / up / down] **and*** show, if no such "resulting smaller parts" clause is specified, the most common "phrasal verb" form is *break [something complex] **down***.

For contexts where the "smaller parts" are unspecified, you *must* include one of the prepositions. It's natural to speak of ***cracking*** a problem (solving it), but you wouldn't normally *crack a paragraph* unless it was some kind of cryptic text that you'd successfully decoded.

It's an *extremely* fine nuance, but I think I can reasonably say that *to break X **up*** is more natural when focusing on the end result being that ***X*** ceases to be the "coherent whole" that it was. Whereas *to break X **down*** works better when focusing on the smaller parts that will thereby result.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. **up** does have some force.

Comment: Having just watched [***Puzzle*** (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6933454/?ref_=nv_sr_1) last night, a possible usage preference occurs to me in the context of a completed jigsaw on the dining room table. *I'll break the puzzle **up** and set the table for dinner* (end result -, the completed puzzle is history, going back into its box), as opposed to *I'll break the puzzle **down** and time how long it takes to complete it again* (end result - the *pieces* are all there ready to be "re-used" in another session).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please provide some solid reference, such as widely recognized online dictionary or grammar book?

Comment: @JJJohn: The two "phrasal verbs" ***to break up*** and ***to break down*** both have quite a range of different meanings - some of which *in some contexts* overlap with the usage involving the *other* preposition. Anyone who doesn't already know most / all of those different meanings (i.e. - just about all non-native speakers) can easily just google **define "to break up"** (or **...down**"). But my example above is a ***very*** extreme "subtle nuance" that might not even be recognised by many/most native speakers, let alone explicitly stated in an authoritative reference book.

Answer (score 1):

I would quibble with the statement by FumbleFingers which says that **up** is vacant of meaning there.

Consider:

> You should break this paragraph.
>
> You should break this paragraph up.

There, the difference is clear.  To "break something up" means to cause it to become *separated*, whereas "to break something" means to fracture it.  **broken up** is the end-state of something which has been broken: not only is there a fracture but the pieces are *apart*.

When you add **into separate pieces**, then you have two things in the statement which convey the idea of "apart", the particle **up** and the prepositional phrase, so it may seems as if **up** has no force, when **into separate pieces** is pleonastic. That's like saying "Mush this into a mush."

**To break something down** is to *decompose* it.

Comment: From my own answer: *For contexts where the "smaller parts" are unspecified, you **must** include one of the prepositions.* Personally I don't find your first (prepositionless) version acceptable at all, but I did go to some trouble to explain that without some additional clause such as ***into smaller sections*** there's a (quite fine) distinction between the overtones of ***break up*** and ***break down*** (both of which can also have ***radically*** different meanings in other contexts, of course).

Comment: **down** is a red herring.   The question is *break* versus *break up*.

Comment: I don't know what you're getting at. Have you actually *read* my answer?

Comment: Yes, I read your answer. I'm disagreeing with the question as formulated by OP and with your answer.

Comment: I'm still lost. I know I switched from ***paragraph*** to ***problem*** in my analysis, which arguably *might* make some slight difference. But the fact of there being an ***into*** clause definitely makes a *lot* of difference, to my mind. Which is why I'm saying I don't much like your first example - with no ***into***, it simply doesn't sit well with me to talk about just "breaking" [paragraphs, problems, sentences, whatever] where the sense is "dividing into smaller parts".

Comment: ...while we're on the subject, you might say *[some complex chemical compound] breaks **down** [into simpler substances]*, but no-one would use ***up*** there. One the other hand, if a large asteroid was on a collision course with the Earth, we'd be launching spacecraft loaded with nuclear bombs in an attempt to break the asteroid ***up***, never ***down***. Which I think reflects my point that ***up*** goes with "complex entity no longer exists", and ***down*** goes with "new parts become available through deconstruction".

Comment: The simple question is, *Is there a difference between "to break something" and "to break something up"?* . Yes, there is. And *Is there a difference between "to break something up" and "to break something down"*? Yes, there is. and *Can a prepositional phrase adjunct muddy those differences?* Yes, it can.

Comment: Well, I certainly can't disagree with anything you said in that last comment! But to be fair, the OP is very specifically focusing on contexts where there is (or at least, in principle *could* be) an ***into...*** clause following. I think trying to cover the vast range of meanings involving ***break*** (with or without prepositions) in other contexts would simply be Too Broad for a single Q and A here.

Comment: ...anyway, it'll be interesting to see how others vote on this one. Which I hope they will do, but it's certainly not attracting much interest as yet!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you please provide some solid reference, such as widely recognized online dictionary or grammar book?